# Null Value error inspite of passing value in Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model in my app like this:

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    bid_amount = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I am trying to save data in this model but keep getting the error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "order_id"
>   violates not-null constraint
>
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (28, null, 800, 2020-06-09
>   12:43:14.697672+00, f, null, 5).

Views.py

```
class BidCreateAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post (self, request, pk, format=None):
        supplier = request.user.pk
        d = request.data.copy()
        print("pk", pk)
        d['order'] = pk
        d['supplier'] = supplier
        print("d is", d)
        serializer = BidSerializer(data=d)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            print("Serializer data", serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Serializer.py

```
class BidSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    order = OrderSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Bid
        fields = "__all__"
```

I have set `required=False` in order serializer then why does it throws the error ?

Comment: You don't  need to add `order = OrderSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, required=False)` in your serializer. `order` field is already present in your model. Try removing it. I generally use different serializer to save objects. So, if you need `OrderSerializer` when using BidSerializer for serializing a big instance, you need to make a different serializer for saving objects.

Comment: actually in another view I am retrieving the `bids` and I need the depth in `order` that is the reason i have kept it, so you are saying that `required=False` does nothing here ?

Comment: Yes, it does nothing for saving. Try making another serializer just for saving purpose.If it works let me know, I will create an answer for same, so that people can see it directly